# R: Widening multiple columns on a single factor variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have an R data frame like this with one factor variable, and two or more value variables.

```
> factorvar <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
> valvar1 <- c(1, 1, 1)
> valvar2 <- c(2, 2, 2)
> df <- data.frame(factorvar, valvar1, valvar2)
> df
  factorvar valvar1 valvar2
1         a       1       2
2         b       1       2
3         c       1       2
```

I want to widen it such that the final data frame looks something like the following:

```
> dfnew
  valvar1.a valvar1.b valvar1.c valvar2.a valvar2.b valvar2.c
  1         1         1         1         2         2         2
```

dplyr/tidyr with spread only allow me to do it for one column (value).

Comment: Melt/gather first so it's fully long, then dcast/spread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses the `dplyr` and `tidyr` libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(valvar, value, -factorvar) %>%
  unite(key, factorvar, valvar) %>%
  mutate(dummy = 1) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  select(-dummy)
```

Which returns:

```
  a_valvar1 a_valvar2 b_valvar1 b_valvar2 c_valvar1 c_valvar2
1         1         2         1         2         1         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `dcast` from the devel version of  `data.table` i.e. `v1.9.5`.  This can take multiple value columns, so you may not need to change the format to `long`.  It can be installed from [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
 library(data.table)
 dcast(setDT(df)[,ind:=1:.N, by = factorvar], ind~factorvar, 
              value.var=c('valvar1', 'valvar2')) 
 #    ind a_valvar1 b_valvar1 c_valvar1 a_valvar2 b_valvar2 c_valvar2
 #1:   1         1         1         1         2         2         2
```

Or a more compact option by @Arun

```
 dcast(setDT(df), . ~ factorvar, value.var=c("valvar1", "valvar2"))
```